# I'm unable to see packet drops after configuration of QoS policy

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, network, qos, policing

I aim to send **iperf** traffic from ***Endpoint1(Client)*** to ***Endpoint2 (Server)*** with the following *SR path* = {*R1, R2, R3, R4, R3, R2, R1, R2, and R3*}. 
[image]
First of all, the traffic generated by **iperf** from ***Endpoint1*** a linearly increasing UDP traffic until I stop manually. Using **SNMP** and **Cacti** I could get throughput across the links *(GRE Tunnels)* which are summarized below.

I set all tunnels' bandwidth as **10Mbps**, I was expecting to see packet loss but I didn't. It is obvious from the plots that the throughput has exceeded the tunnels' bandwidth. However, no packet loss is recorded.

Therefore, I configured *Policing* bandwidth on the interface's tunnel as the following:

```
class-map match-all acgroup2
 match access-group 2
!
policy-map police
 class acgroup2
  police cir 10000000
   conform-action transmit 
   exceed-action drop 
   violate-action drop
```

However, after sending the traffic, I could not see any drops of traffic on the interface even it's exceeded the bandwidth tunnel.

```
#show policy-map interface
Tunnel0 

  Service-policy input: POLICER

    Class-map: acgroup2 (match-all)  
      0 packets, 0 bytes
      30 second offered rate 0000 bps, drop rate 0000 bps
      Match: none 
      police:
          cir 10000000 bps, bc 312500 bytes, be 312500 bytes
        conformed 0 packets, 0 bytes; actions:
          transmit 
        exceeded 0 packets, 0 bytes; actions:
          drop 
        violated 0 packets, 0 bytes; actions:
          drop 
        conformed 0000 bps, exceeded 0000 bps, violated 0000 bps

    Class-map: class-default (match-any)  
      323771 packets, 261795856 bytes
      30 second offered rate 8731000 bps, drop rate 0000 bps
      Match: any 
 Tunnel1 

  Service-policy input: POLICER

    Class-map: acgroup2 (match-all)  
      0 packets, 0 bytes
      30 second offered rate 0000 bps, drop rate 0000 bps
      Match: none 
      police:
          cir 10000000 bps, bc 312500 bytes, be 312500 bytes
        conformed 0 packets, 0 bytes; actions:
          transmit 
        exceeded 0 packets, 0 bytes; actions:
          drop 
        violated 0 packets, 0 bytes; actions:
          drop 
        conformed 0000 bps, exceeded 0000 bps, violated 0000 bps

    Class-map: class-default (match-any)  
      857218 packets, 694258348 bytes
      30 second offered rate 22024000 bps, drop rate 0000 bps
      Match: any
```

Whatever the amount of traffic sent, the values of **conformed**, **exceeded** and **violated** did not change at all.

This is the important router's configuration

R1

```
    segment-routing mpls
 global-block 17000 18000
 !
 connected-prefix-sid-map
  address-family ipv4
   11.11.11.11/32 index 11 range 1 
  exit-address-family
!
class-map match-all acgroup2
     match access-group 100
    !
    policy-map police
     class acgroup2
      police cir 8000000
       conform-action transmit 
       exceed-action drop 
       violate-action drop 
    !
    interface Loopback0
     ip address 11.11.11.11 255.255.255.255
    !
    interface Tunnel0
     bandwidth 10000
     ip flow monitor NTAMonitor input
     ip flow monitor NTAMonitor output
     ip address 10.10.1.1 255.255.255.252
     ip router isis aws
     load-interval 30
     mpls traffic-eng tunnels
     keepalive 2 3
     tunnel source GigabitEthernet1
     tunnel destination 52.27.173.12
     tunnel path-mtu-discovery
     isis metric 1
     service-policy output police
    !
    interface Tunnel1
     bandwidth 10000
     ip flow monitor NTAMonitor input
     ip flow monitor NTAMonitor output
     ip address 10.10.4.2 255.255.255.252
     ip router isis aws
     load-interval 30
     mpls traffic-eng tunnels
     keepalive 2 3
     tunnel source GigabitEthernet1
     tunnel destination 54.70.66.102
     tunnel path-mtu-discovery
     isis metric 1
     service-policy output police
    !
    interface Tunnel4
     description MPLS TE Tunnel1 to the destination for path SR1
     ip unnumbered Loopback0
     tunnel mode mpls traffic-eng
     tunnel destination 33.33.33.33
     tunnel mpls traffic-eng autoroute announce
     tunnel mpls traffic-eng path-option 1 explicit name SR1 segment-routing verbatim
    !
    interface Tunnel5
     description MPLS TE Tunnel2 to the destination for path SR2
     ip unnumbered Loopback0
     tunnel mode mpls traffic-eng
     tunnel destination 33.33.33.33
     tunnel mpls traffic-eng autoroute announce
     tunnel mpls traffic-eng path-option 1 explicit name SR2 segment-routing verbatim
    !         
    interface VirtualPortGroup0
     vrf forwarding GS
     ip address 192.168.35.101 255.255.255.0
     ip nat inside
     no mop enabled
     no mop sysid
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet1
     ip flow monitor NTAMonitor input
     ip flow monitor NTAMonitor output
     ip address dhcp
     ip nat outside
     load-interval 30
     negotiation auto
     ipv6 address dhcp
     ipv6 enable
     no mop enabled
     no mop sysid
     service-policy output police
    !
    router isis aws
     net 49.0001.0000.0000.0011.00
     metric-style wide
     segment-routing mpls
     segment-routing prefix-sid-map advertise-local
     passive-interface Loopback0
     mpls traffic-eng router-id Loopback0
    !
    iox
    ip forward-protocol nd
    ip tcp window-size 8192
    ip http server
    ip http authentication local
    ip http secure-server
    ip nat inside source list GS_NAT_ACL interface GigabitEthernet1 vrf GS overload
    ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet1 172.0.1.1
    ip route 33.33.33.33 255.255.255.255 Tunnel4
    ip route 33.33.33.33 255.255.255.255 Tunnel5
    ip route 172.2.1.5 255.255.255.255 Tunnel4
    ip route 172.2.1.7 255.255.255.255 Tunnel5
    ip route vrf GS 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet1 172.0.1.1 global
    !
    ip explicit-path name SR1 enable
     index 1 next-label 17022
     index 2 next-label 17033
     index 3 next-label 17044
     index 4 next-label 17033
     index 5 next-label 17022
     index 6 next-label 17011
     index 7 next-label 17022
     index 8 next-label 17033
    !
    ip ssh rsa keypair-name ssh-key
    ip ssh version 2
    ip ssh pubkey-chain
    ip scp server enable
    !
    access-list 100 permit ip any any
    ipv6 route ::/0 GigabitEthernet1 FE80::83F:37FF:FE14:2840
    !
    !
    snmp-server community public RO
    snmp-server community private RW
    !
    !
    control-plane
    !
    line con 0
     stopbits 1
    line vty 0 4
     login local
     transport input ssh
    !
    app-hosting appid guestshell
     app-vnic gateway1 virtualportgroup 0 guest-interface 0
      guest-ipaddress 192.168.35.102 netmask 255.255.255.0
     app-default-gateway 192.168.35.101 guest-interface 0
     name-server0 8.8.8.8
    end
```

R2

```
segment-routing mpls
 global-block 17000 18000
 !
 connected-prefix-sid-map
  address-family ipv4
   22.22.22.22/32 index 22 range 1 
  exit-address-family
 !
!
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
netconf-yang
!
restconf
!
redundancy    
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 22.22.22.22 255.255.255.255
!
interface Tunnel0
 bandwidth 10000
 ip flow monitor NTAMonitor input
 ip flow monitor NTAMonitor output
 ip address 10.10.2.1 255.255.255.252
 ip router isis aws
 load-interval 30
 mpls traffic-eng tunnels
 keepalive 2 3
 tunnel source GigabitEthernet1
 tunnel destination 52.38.167.137
 tunnel path-mtu-discovery
 isis metric 1
!
interface Tunnel1
 bandwidth 10000
 ip flow monitor NTAMonitor input
 ip flow monitor NTAMonitor output
 ip address 10.10.1.2 255.255.255.252
 ip router isis aws
 load-interval 30
 mpls traffic-eng tunnels
 keepalive 2 3
 tunnel source GigabitEthernet1
 tunnel destination 35.167.193.103
 tunnel path-mtu-discovery
 isis metric 1
!
interface VirtualPortGroup0
 vrf forwarding GS
 ip address 192.168.35.101 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 no mop enabled
 no mop sysid
!
interface GigabitEthernet1
 ip flow monitor NTAMonitor input
 ip flow monitor NTAMonitor output
 ip address dhcp
 ip nat outside
 load-interval 30
 negotiation auto
 ipv6 address dhcp
 ipv6 enable
 no mop enabled
 no mop sysid
!
router isis aws
 net 49.0001.0000.0000.0022.00
 metric-style wide
 segment-routing mpls
 segment-routing prefix-sid-map advertise-local
 passive-interface Loopback0
 mpls traffic-eng router-id Loopback0
!
iox
ip forward-protocol nd
ip tcp window-size 8192
ip http server
ip http authentication local
ip http secure-server
ip nat inside source list GS_NAT_ACL interface GigabitEthernet1 vrf GS overload
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet1 172.1.1.1
ip route vrf GS 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet1 172.1.1.1 global
!
ip ssh rsa keypair-name ssh-key
ip ssh version 2
ip scp server enable
!
!
ip access-list standard GS_NAT_ACL
 permit 192.168.35.0 0.0.0.255
ipv6 route ::/0 GigabitEthernet1 FE80::83E:87FF:FEAA:8604
!      
snmp-server community public RO
snmp-server community private RW
!
!
control-plane
!
line con 0
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 login local
 transport input ssh
!
app-hosting appid guestshell
 app-vnic gateway1 virtualportgroup 0 guest-interface 0
  guest-ipaddress 192.168.35.102 netmask 255.255.255.0
 app-default-gateway 192.168.35.101 guest-interface 0
 name-server0 8.8.8.8
end
```

R3

```
segment-routing mpls
 global-block 17000 18000
 !
 connected-prefix-sid-map
  address-family ipv4
   33.33.33.33/32 index 33 range 1 
  exit-address-family
 !
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
netconf-yang
!
restconf
!
!
redundancy
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 33.33.33.33 255.255.255.255
!
interface Tunnel0
 bandwidth 10000
 ip flow monitor NTAMonitor input
 ip flow monitor NTAMonitor output
 ip address 10.10.3.1 255.255.255.252
 ip router isis aws
 load-interval 30
 mpls traffic-eng tunnels
 keepalive 2 3
 tunnel source GigabitEthernet1
 tunnel destination 54.70.66.102
 tunnel path-mtu-discovery
 isis metric 1
!
interface Tunnel1
 bandwidth 10000
 ip flow monitor NTAMonitor input
 ip flow monitor NTAMonitor output
 ip address 10.10.2.2 255.255.255.252
 ip router isis aws
 load-interval 30
 mpls traffic-eng tunnels
 keepalive 2 3
 tunnel source GigabitEthernet1
 tunnel destination 52.27.173.12
 tunnel path-mtu-discovery
 isis metric 1
!
interface VirtualPortGroup0
 vrf forwarding GS
 ip address 192.168.35.101 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 no mop enabled
 no mop sysid
!
interface GigabitEthernet1
 ip flow monitor NTAMonitor input
 ip flow monitor NTAMonitor output
 ip address dhcp
 ip nat outside
 load-interval 30
 negotiation auto
 ipv6 address dhcp
 ipv6 enable
 no mop enabled
 no mop sysid
 service-policy input police
!
router isis aws
 net 49.0001.0000.0000.0033.00
 metric-style wide
 segment-routing mpls
 segment-routing prefix-sid-map advertise-local
 passive-interface Loopback0
 mpls traffic-eng router-id Loopback0
!
iox
ip forward-protocol nd
ip tcp window-size 8192
ip http server
ip http authentication local
ip http secure-server
ip nat inside source list GS_NAT_ACL interface GigabitEthernet1 vrf GS overload
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet1 172.2.1.1
ip route 172.0.1.0 255.255.255.240 11.11.11.11
ip route vrf GS 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet1 172.2.1.1 global
!
ip ssh rsa keypair-name ssh-key
ip ssh version 2
ip ssh pubkey-chain
ip scp server enable
!
ip access-list standard GS_NAT_ACL
 permit 192.168.35.0 0.0.0.255
ipv6 route ::/0 GigabitEthernet1 FE80::893:B3FF:FED5:7104      
!
snmp-server community public RO
snmp-server community private RW
!
control-plane
!
line con 0
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 login local
 transport input ssh
!
app-hosting appid guestshell
 app-vnic gateway1 virtualportgroup 0 guest-interface 0
  guest-ipaddress 192.168.35.102 netmask 255.255.255.0
 app-default-gateway 192.168.35.101 guest-interface 0
 name-server0 8.8.8.8
end
```

R4

```
segment-routing mpls
 global-block 17000 18000
 !
 connected-prefix-sid-map
  address-family ipv4
   44.44.44.44/32 index 44 range 1 
  exit-address-family
 !
!
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
netconf-yang
!
restconf
!

!
redundancy
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 44.44.44.44 255.255.255.255
!
interface Tunnel0
 bandwidth 10000
 ip flow monitor NTAMonitor input
 ip flow monitor NTAMonitor output
 ip address 10.10.4.1 255.255.255.252
 ip router isis aws
 load-interval 30
 mpls traffic-eng tunnels
 keepalive 2 3
 tunnel source GigabitEthernet1
 tunnel destination 35.167.193.103
 tunnel path-mtu-discovery
 isis metric 1
!
interface Tunnel1
 bandwidth 10000
 ip flow monitor NTAMonitor input
 ip flow monitor NTAMonitor output
 ip address 10.10.3.2 255.255.255.252
 ip router isis aws
 load-interval 30
 mpls traffic-eng tunnels
 keepalive 2 3
 tunnel source GigabitEthernet1
 tunnel destination 52.38.167.137
 tunnel path-mtu-discovery
 isis metric 1
!
interface VirtualPortGroup0
 vrf forwarding GS
 ip address 192.168.35.101 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 no mop enabled
 no mop sysid
!
interface GigabitEthernet1
 ip flow monitor NTAMonitor input
 ip flow monitor NTAMonitor output
 ip address dhcp
 ip nat outside
 load-interval 30
 negotiation auto
 ipv6 address dhcp
 ipv6 enable
 no mop enabled
 no mop sysid
!
router isis aws
 net 49.0001.0000.0000.0044.00
 metric-style wide
 segment-routing mpls
 segment-routing prefix-sid-map advertise-local
 passive-interface Loopback0
 mpls traffic-eng router-id Loopback0
!
iox
ip forward-protocol nd
ip tcp window-size 8192
ip http server
ip http authentication local
ip http secure-server
ip nat inside source list GS_NAT_ACL interface GigabitEthernet1 vrf GS overload
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet1 172.3.1.1
ip route vrf GS 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet1 172.3.1.1 global
!
ip ssh rsa keypair-name ssh-key
ip ssh version 2
ip ssh pubkey-chain
ip scp server enable
!
ip access-list standard GS_NAT_ACL
 permit 192.168.35.0 0.0.0.255
ipv6 route ::/0 GigabitEthernet1 FE80::D:1CFF:FE1E:97C2
!       
snmp-server community private RW
snmp-server community public RO
!
control-plane
!
line con 0
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 login local
 transport input ssh
!
app-hosting appid guestshell
 app-vnic gateway1 virtualportgroup 0 guest-interface 0
  guest-ipaddress 192.168.35.102 netmask 255.255.255.0
 app-default-gateway 192.168.35.101 guest-interface 0
 name-server0 8.8.8.8
end
```

Comment: According to what you have, you have not matched any packets. Please edit your question to include the full router configurations. We cannot guess where you may have gone wrong.

Comment: @RonMaupin I just edited my question.

Comment: Well, no wonder you are not matching anything. You are matching on `ip address 11.11.11.11 255.255.255.255`, but you have no such address anywhere in the network. If you really want help, then you need to include the full router configurations for all the routers.

Comment: @RonMaupin Sorry :) just added the whole configuration of the 4 routers

Comment: Now, you have removed the access list used in the match. You are also, trying to limit traffic from Endpoint1 to Endpoint2 on R1, but you are applying the the service policy as inbound from the other end of the tunnel, not outbound from R1.

Comment: @RonMaupin oh thanks, Ron! How do I fix this? would you please explain to me how to fix this?

Comment: There are several ways that you could do this. For example, create the ACL for the match as an extended ACL for traffic from Endpoint1 to Endpoint2, and apply the service policy inbound on the interface where Endpoint1 connects to R1.

Comment: @RonMaupin I've added `access-list 100 permit ip any any` where I could see drops only on the `GigabitEthernet1` using `show policy-map interface g1 output`. However, ICMP report does not show any drops.

Comment: Khalil, you obviously have some errors in your configuration.  But we can't see them unless you update the configurations in your original question.

Comment: Drops caused by QoS do not generate ICMP messages.

Comment: @RonMaupin Sorry, typo mistake, I meant SNMP

Comment: @RonTrunk Sorry, just updated the content of R1 configuration. the other routers remain the same.

Comment: The service policy is in the wrong direction.  You have it on the output of the tunnel, which would be traffic going **to endpoint 1.**